# Como trabajo con un array que pasa como parametro?

Tags: java

Hola tengo un parcial dentro de poco sobre algoritmos y estaba practicando, un ejercicio es este:

```
/**
 * Este método toma un array de enteros como parámetro y devuelve
 * el mayor elemento de dicho array
 * **/

public int buscarMayor(int[] arr) {
    
}
```

como hago para trabajar con el array del parametro,lo tengo que crear en el metodo o simplemente usar con el nombre del parametro?
Intente usar el .sort pero no me deja.

Comment: Hola Matias, bienvenido, te sugiero que agregues el código que has intentado como texto, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Si, una forma de encontrar el máximo es ordenar el arreglo. Entonces el máximo se encontrará al final. Aunque quizás no sea la idea que uses funciones que hagan todo el trabajo por ti. Sino que esperen que recorras el arreglo para determinar cuál es el mayor.

Comment: Por cierto, aclara la pregunta. No estamos seguros de si tienes un problema de interpretación o qué es exactamente a lo que deberíamos responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar una función, tal como solicitas puedes hacerlo directamente siempre que este sea transferido correctamente como argumento en la función.

```
public int buscarMayor(int arr[]) {
        Arrays.sort(arr); //<--Aca usamos directamente el arreglo
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    }
```

Considerar también lo indicado por Mateo puesto que usar métodos que realicen el ordenamiento de manera directa, no necesariamente sería valido en el contexto de una prueba algorítmica.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo básico.

```
                              // parámetro recibido
public int buscarMayor( int[] arr ) {

                        // tomamos como dato el largo del array
    for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

        // acá asignamos a la posición **i** del array algo
        arr[ i ] = algo;
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude a entender.

Comment: Creo que en realidad OP tenía un problema de interpretación. Me refiero, quizá no le queda claro que recibe un arreglo como parámetro y lo único que tiene que hacer es procesarlo. Por lo tanto el encargado de crear el arreglo es quien llame a la función.